# How to create a array of elements in range?

Tags: java

In `Java`, is there any way to create a array of elements in range?

For example,

```
new int[] {1:10}, which should be equivalent to,
new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

I was thinking, if we need to create a array of large range elements (5-1000), rather than writing it like 5, 6, ..., 1000, if there is way like 5:1000.

Answer (score 8):

In Java 8

```
int[] array = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).toArray();
```

Comment: Great this is, alas I'm using Java 7 environment in production!

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built-in language feature, but you can easily create a method that does it:

```
public static int[] createIntRangeArray(int start, int end) {
    int[] result = new int[end-start+1];
    for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        result[i-start] = i;
    return result;
}
```

and then:

```
createIntRangeArray(1, 10)
// is equivalent to
new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

Comment: There may be a built-in *method* that I'm not aware of, especially with Java 8 streams.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ArrayGenerator {
    public static int[] generateArray(int start, int end) {
        int[] array = new int[end-start+1];
        for(int i=start;i<=end;i++) {
            array[i-start] = i;
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

//this can be used like

```
    int start = 5;
    int end = 10;
    int[] generatedArray = ArrayGenerator.generateArray(start,end);

    for(int i : generatedArray) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Comment: The range has start and end indices. You should not assume it to be starting with 0 always.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing a separate method containing a loop which initializes your array.

```
public int[] createArrayWithRange(int startIncl, int endIncl) {
    int[] nums = new int[endIncl - startIncl + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < (endIncl - startIncl + 1) ; i++) {
        nums[i] = i + startIncl;
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposition:

```
public List<Integer> generateIntTab(int size){
        List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
            x.add((i << 1)-i+1);
        }
        return x;
    }
```

Its a bit slower then standard JDK8 function which give @Reimeus